# Keras delayed data augmentation

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to apply a custom image augmentation technique in Keras. I am using fit_generator and a generator to yield images. I would like to start applying the image augmentation only after say 20 epochs (So the first 20 epochs would not have any data augmentation). Unfortunately the generator does not have a notion of epochs. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: why not fit on two different generators - one without the augmentations and one with the augmentations?

Comment: How would you switch from one to the other based on the epoch?

Comment: Well... train for 20 epochs, change generator, train for more epochs...

Comment: This is even better because `steps_per_epoch` should also change.

Comment: Sounds good but what I dont get is how to change the generator while training. at the moment I have something like: model.fit_generator(myGenerator((x_train, y_train),batch_size, alpha ) , steps_per_epoch=60000//batch_size ,epochs=200,validation_data=myGeneratorTT((x_test, y_test),batch_size, alpha ), validation_steps=10000//batch_size, callbacks=[F1F1,checkpointer])  , which is not inside a loop, and does all the training for me

Comment: You probably mean, I should have 2 of those then ...one fit_generator with 20 epochs and with the generator that doesn't data augment, and one fit_generator after that with the generator that actually augments the images. Think I get it! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is train for 20 epochs with no realtime augmentation (use the Keras ImageDataGenerator with no args) and save your models using a ModelCheckpoint callback. Then reload the model and continue training with RA (use an ImageDataGenerator with the transforms of your choice).

If you want that behavior in one step, you can make your own version of ImageDataGenerator. You just need to make the following changes:

```
def __init__(self,
             batch_counter=0,  # count the batches elapsed
             steps_per_epoch=0,  # pass steps per epoch into the custom ImageDataGenerator on init
             n_epoch = 0, # count the epochs elapsed
```

Then, just modify the NumpyArrayIterator in your ImageDataGenerator to increment these variables and only call random_transform after your n_epochs have elapsed. E.g. self.image_data_generator.batch_counter += 1